# Accessing values in Drupal's $form_values from a custom Drupal Form

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-forms

**EDIT:** Seems like my "array-crawling" skills were not enough, thanks for the suggestions.
Moreover, I found out that I was checking the $discounttype condition with a plain "=" instead of a double "==".  I guess banging your head on the same block of code for 3 hours makes you dumb and miss the most obvious errors.

First thing first, I'm on Drupal 6.

I have created a form with the following markup:

```
$form["cart_".$index] = array(
'#type' => 'image_button',
'#src'=> 'files/imghome/sidebar-add-demo.gif',
'#attributes' => array('rel' => '#item', 'class' => 'buybutton', 'title' => $discounttype),
'#prefix'=>'<p class="renewprop">'.$newren.' for '.$node_abb->field_tipo_abb_value.':</p><p class="renewblock"><span class="pricetag">'.$node_abb->field_prezzo_value.''.$discounttype.'</span>',
'#suffix' =>'</p>' ,
'#submit' =>array('usercp_form_submit'),
);
```

The form renders correctly, as you can see from this picture: http://cl.ly/3D2C2h1t1m2B351L1T31
(the N and R values beside the € symbol are actually the value of the $discounttype variable, just for checking it)

Each white box is basically an istance of the beforementioned form.

I need to pass the value of the $discounttype variable on each submit, so I decided to set it as the title of the submit button.

My problem is that in the submit function itself I cannot access the value of the 'title' attribute contained in the #attributes array. Mainly because probably I don't know the right syntax.

So far I've tried

```
$foo = $form_values['attributes']['title'];
$foo = $form_values['#attributes']['title'];
$foo = $form_values['attributes']['#title'];
```

And every other possible combination, but probably I'm just doing it wrong.
It's actually an hour that I'm crawling the web searching for an asnwer but I came up with anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you should mention form element ID.
so, you can access submit button by `$form_state["cart_".$index]['#attributes']['title'];`
but actually, why don't you use hidden field ('#type' => 'hidden') ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use `$form_state` instead of `$form_values`. Give this a try:

```
$foo = $form_state['clicked_button']['#attributes']['title'];
```

I recommend using the [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) while developing for Drupal.  It is an extremely helpful tool during development, allowing you to see all the queries run when a page loads, stop a redirect to debug, and **much more**.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'm actually using Devel to debug things, see array values and such, and that's where I can see that the 'title' attribute is correctly set. 

Seems like I still cannot access that value from the string you've proposed.

I still can't figure out how to access that damn array.

Still thanks for the suggestion.